# JS code to change table caption to display when overflow scroll bar appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to this site so forgive me if I've posted incorrectly!

I'm trying to write JS so that the table caption property in a table appears when the overflow of a table causes a scroll bar to appear, (most likely on a mobile device or due window re-sizing). How would I go about doing this? My current code for the table is:

```
.datatable table{
          max-width: 100%;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow-x:auto;
        }
```

I want to be able to set:

```
.datatable table caption{
    display:none;
}
```

To something else once the overflow scroll bar appears using JS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this will add your css class if it has vertical scrollbar
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        if(this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.get(0).clientHeight){
    $("tableid").addClass("yourCssClass");
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#tableid').hasScrollBar();
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `this` is a jQuery collection, so you'd need to iterate over each element in that collection (rather than simply using the first), and you should also `return this` in order to preserve chaining.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Sunil you would then have a css class added to your style sheet called yourCssClass e.g:

```
.yourCssClass{display:none;}
```